# what is the purpose and consequences of Eigenvalues in graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am trying to understand Eigenvalues and their repercussions in graph theory. I have read that Eigenvalues help describe certain parameters of graphs which provide information about the general structure of graphs.
I know that we can take the adjacency matrix of a given graph, and obtain the eigenvalues, but I don't understand their consequences and what they tell us about a graph. Any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: I’ve always been curious about this myself. It might help would-be answerers to know roughly how much you understand about eigenvalues, or adjacency matrices for that matter.

Comment: Thanks @TheoBendit. What I know about the adjacency matrix is that it refers to a 0-1 matrix, where 1 represents two vertices are connected by an edge, and 0 otherwise. Also, the adjacency matrix is a square and symmetric matrix. Eigenvalues represent the solutions to a given adjacency matrix. What does that mean? I can multiply the eigenvalue to an eigenvector along with the identity matrix and get the graph of the adjacency matrix. In linear algebra we used eigenvalues to represent the scaling of a vector. Are we using them now to represent the scaling of a graph?

Comment: Since no one more knowledgeable is answering, let me engage in some spit-balling. The largest eigenvalue of a diagonalisable matrix is the operator norm of the matrix. Moreover, for such a matrix $A$, $\|A^n\| = \|A\|^n$. In the case of an adjacency matrix, the entries of $A^n$ counts the number of trails of length $n$. So, in this way, the largest eigenvalue of $A$ indicates roughly how "rich" the graph is in long trails. I don't study graph theory at all, but that's the connection my brain has made.

Comment: There are at least two closely related kinds of matrices, the adjacency matrix (generalized to the incidence matrix for directed graphs) and the Laplacian. The Laplacian has the spectral theory that I know anything nontrivial about. There are some trivial eigenvalues of the Laplacian that just describe the connected components of the graph (strongly connected, in the directed graph setting).

Comment: (Cont.) After that you have eigenvalues which intuitively describe how fast different perturbations from an invariant distribution will relax under a discrete time random walk (thus they roughly describe how easy it is to get from one place to another). A slow relaxation could be caused by, for example, a single edge that if deleted would split the graph into two connected components.

Comment: @learning_mathematician rather than "scaling of a graph," think "probability density along the graph" and I think it'll make a lot more sense

Comment: There are many books on spectral graph theory- this isn't a question that can reasonably be answered on math.stackexchange.

Comment: I am asking for some intuition and key consequences. What I have read so far only provides process and definitions.